# +/- quantity of products in Cart View Controller with buttons each on a TableViewCell, which gets default quantity as integer from an array

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

i am developing an app that you could add items to the Cart from MenuVC, then you can go to CartVC to view what is on your cart and increase or decrease quantity of items to be ordered. I cant make quantity label to change, don't know if thats because i get quantity from an array? is it unmutable?

Thank you for your help

Here is my cell

```
import UIKit

class BasketCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var quantityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

var buttonIncrease : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?
var buttonDecrease : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


@IBAction func increaseQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonIncrease?(self)
}

@IBAction func decreaseQuantity(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonDecrease?(self)
}
```

here is my example 2d array which i append it from web service

```
var items = 
    [
        ["Cheeseburger","Pizza","Sprite","Redbull"],
        ["10 $","20 $","5 $","6 $"],
        [1,1,2,1,2]
    ]
```

and here is my cellForRowAt @CartVC

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basketCell", for: indexPath) as! BasketCell

    cell.quantityLabel.text = String(items[2][indexPath.row] as! Int)

    cell.buttonIncrease = { (cell) in
        var quantity = self.items[2][indexPath.row] as! Int
        quantity += 1
        self.tableView1.reloadData()
    }
    cell.buttonDecrease = { (cell) in
        var quantity = self.items[2][indexPath.row] as! Int
        if quantity > 1 {
        quantity -= 1
        self.tableView1.reloadData()
        }
    }

    cell.itemLabel.text = items[0][indexPath.row] as? String
    cell.priceLabel.text = items[1][indexPath.row] as? String

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but using an array of arrays for your data model is far from ideal. Define a `struct` with three properties for name, price, and quantity. Then have a single array of those structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it unmutable?

When you declare new variable by downcasting some element from array of `Any` objects, you get copy of this element which has no reference to element from array.

---

For your case would be better if you have your custom model

```
struct Item: Codable { // if you get this data from web service, you can use `JSONDecoder` to decode `Data` to `Item`/`[Item]`
    var title: String
    var price: String // better: `var price: Int` and then when you need to get text just add `" $"`
    var quantity: Int
}
```

then you can have your `items` array as array of `Item` objects

```
var items = [Item(title: "Cheeseburger", price: "10 $", quantity: 1), ...]
```

now you can get certain item from `items` in `cellForRowAt` as element from `items` with index equal to `indexPath.row`

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
cell.quantityLabel.text = String(item.quantity)
```

And when you need to change it's amount property

```
self.items[indexPath.row].quantity += 1
```

Comment: i am new to swift, how can i create that struct dynamically? i gave that array as example, i will get three types of elements from web service. how can i append them into that struct?

Comment: @DorukÇoban What do you get from service? Title, price, quantity, etc.?

Comment: @DorukÇoban anyway, look to edited answer. You can implement `Encodable` and `Decodable` protocols to your struct: `struct Item: Codable` and then you can simply decode data from web service using `JSONDecoder`

Comment: title: String 
price: String
quantity: Integer as json.  i think i should search to extract data into struct since i cant change the value of array element

Comment: @DorukÇoban look, now you have struct. Now learn something about `Codable`. There are lot of another questions about `Codable` protocol, so search...

Comment: eyeing some tutorials, it seems reliable in my case. thank you,

Comment: @DorukÇoban Ok. Good luck! I hope my answer helped you little bit.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. the reason i use 2d arrays commonly, i use them for creating sections